# object litrals Instantiation not working

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have created an object through literals and instantiating using 'new' operator. But that's not working. Here is my code:

```
var rectangle = { 
    upperLeft : { x : 2, y : 2 },
    lowerRight : { x : 4, y : 4}
}
var r=new rectangle;
alert(r.upperLeft.x) // will yield 2
```

I have tried using Parentheses after the object name while instantiating:

```
var r=new rectangle;
```

But that's also not working. I have tried creating object using function statement and that's working fine, but I want to do it this way. Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rectangle` is, as you noticed, an `Object Literal`. It's not a Constructor function, it's a single instance of `Object`. If you want `rectangle` to have more instances, use something like:

```
function Rectangle(ul,lr){
  var default = {x:0,y:0};
  return {
          upperLeft: ul || default, 
          lowerRight: lr || default 
         };
}

var r1 = new Rectangle({x:2,y:2},{x:4,y:4}),
    r2 = new Rectangle({x:3,y:3},{x:5,y:5}),
    r3 = new Rectangle;

r1.upperleft.x; //=> 2
r2.upperleft.x; //=> 3
r3.upperLeft.x = 5;
r3.upperLeft.y = 7;
alert(r3.upperLeft.x; //=> 5
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably mean

```
var r = Object.create(rectangle);
```

Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/Cra8Q/

**ADDENDUM**

The "old" way in JavaScript to create a bunch of rectangles is to use the `new` operator.  The way to do that is like this:

```
function Rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
    this.upperLeft = {x: x1, y: y1};
    this.lowerRight = {x: x2, y: y2};
}

var r = new Rectangle(2, 2, 4, 4);

alert(r.upperLeft.x);
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/uDs3N/

The problem with the code in the question was that `rectangle` was an actual rectangle object and not a constructor, so it could not be used with `new`.  The operator `new` can only be used before a function call.

That said, the more modern approach is to go with the creation of the prototypical rectangle object, and derive new rectangles with `Object.create`.  However, the constructor approach is still popular.

Comment: Yeah that's working but whats the problem with using new operator? and Will constructors work this was?

Comment: Oh, if your intent was to use _constructors_ I will add that to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The other way to create an object with "new" operator is to define a constructor function, like this:

```
var Rectangle = function()
{
    this.upperLeft = { x : 2, y : 2 },
    this.lowerRight = { x : 4, y : 4}
}

var rect = new Rectangle();
alert(rect.upperLeft.x);
```

Comment: If you have read the question, I have mentioned that I have tried creating object using function statement and that's working fine, but I want to do it this way. Thanx

Comment: You can't use "new" with object literals in pure JS. Only with functions. To create an object from a literal you should create a hand-made "clone" function or use already provided in frameworks for example.

Answer (score 0):

The `new` operator takes a *function*, not an object. What you're trying won't work.

This is how `new` works:

```
function Rectangle() {
    this.upperLeft = {x: 2, y: 2};
    this.lowerRight = {x: 4, y: 4};
}

var r = new Rectangle();
```

Part of the operation of `var r = new Rectangle()` is similar to this:

```
var r = {};
Rectangle.call(r); // makes r available as `this` in the function
```

This is **far from equivalent to what `new` does**; it's leaving out all kinds of prototype magic and other things.

But it shows why the argument to `new` needs to be a function.